# Compiling static template functions on AIX 7.1 xlc++

Tags: c++, aix, dbx

Our source code has a bunch of standalone static template functions. I need to compile it on AIX 7.1 Power 7 system with IBM's native `xlc++` compiler. Using `static` keyword with standalone functions is obsoleted practice and it's not supported by `xlc++`, so to get my program compiled I removed that keyword from function declarations. After the program compiled successfully, the first run crashed ( on `Linux/g++` it's perfectly stable with the same input data).

I tried to debug with `dbx`, but debugger complained about `internal error` and `segmentation fault in extend_brk`. No memory quotas is used, so it's not a memory/disk space shortage. System is configured to create full core dump, program compiled with `-g` option. All libraries are linked statically, so it's not a problem with throwing exceptions in shared libraries.
   1) Is it possible to compile static template functions on `xlc++` without removing `static` keyword, so I can be sure that all code is the same as in RHEL system?
   2) Why debugger doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I had 32/64 bit portability issue, removing **static** keyword is harmless in that situation.
Problem had gone away after I added the following line at my .kshrc file:

```
export OBJECT_MODE=64
```

By default, IBM XL compilers run in 32 bit mode, even on 64 bit AIX 7.1 systems. To overwrite default behavior, programmer can set environment variable or supply -q64 parameter to compiler.